# SignalR some time works and some times don't

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr, chat, jquery-events

I have a chat application that was developed with the help of asp.net signalR. It was working fine but now it has been fall into a issue that when page loads and when I refreshes a page it randomly works and some times don't. The problem is the hub class function is not able to call the client side method. Here is my code of chat.html

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log("Connected, transport = " +
        $.connection.hub.transport.name);
    var userId = "29265";
    var name = "MY NAME";
    var uri = window.location.pathname;
    chat.server.onconnected(userId, name, uri);
});

chat.client.updateSender = function(usr, json)
{
    console.log(json);
};
```

Hub.cs:

```
public void Onconnected(string chatUserId, string name, string pageUrl)
{
    if(chatUserId != "0")
    {
        var conId = Context.ConnectionId;
        Groups.Add(conId, chatUserId);
        Clients.Group(chatUserId).updateSender(usr, chatUserId + "~" + conId);
    }
}
```

some times, It calls updateSender method without any issue and some time it don't. I will be very thankfull for your help.

Comment: Not too familiar with SignalR yet but wondering, on this line - `.start().done(function()...`, what happens when the hub is already started? Does it restart every time, or if it's already running, does it skip the 'done' function?

Comment: No, It just start the connection with hub class(proxy class), means initialize the connection hub.